# Mobile device cannot access MAMP servier

Tags: php, android, mamp

I have a web service that is hosted on my MAMP server. The ip address that I got was http://192.168.1.5:80/gca.php. However, I cannot seem to be able to access this site from any physical mobile device. When I load up the emulator in my computer, it manages to connect to it. Any other device that loads the app gets a org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.5:80 refused. 
Hopefully someone can help as I've been stuck with this issue suddenly

EDIT : This issue happened after I moved the receiver and service tags inside the application tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.amosang.pushtest" >

<!-- GCM Permissions - Start here  -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.example.amosang.pushtest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
</application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: Sounds like most likely a firewall is blocking requests to the system from outside. That does make sense, _except_ obviously if you want to _allow_ such access.

Comment: I haven't switched on any firewalls though? Do I have to do anything to me httpd.conf?

Comment: OK, if you are certain that no firewall sits in between and you suspect that the http server itself refuses the request, then take a look into your http servers error log file. In that case you definitely should see something in there.

Comment: I've just checked the logs, it doesn't seem to show anything so far. This issue started when I edited my Android manifest file though. I'll post it up

Comment: At least the request has to show up in the access log file, otherwise your requests _are_ blocked before on network level. So either a firewall or a routing issue.

Comment: I just enabled my access log and tried again. Still no luck there. Firewall is definitely off.

Comment: Another firewall in between "device" and http server system? A routing issue? What is your network topology for the requests?

Comment: Wait no idea how, but when i copied and pasted my code out from the application tag , ran the app, recopied it into the application tag, it worked.

Comment: No idea what that actually means. I am not an Android developer. But anyway, glad that things work!